# Mage.php unable to find module class files

Tags: magento-1.9, module, class

We have a Magento 1.9.2.4 site that works perfectly on our development server, but when deployed to production, throws errors that it can't find custom module classes (`Mage_Ultimo_Helper_Cssgen` is one example, it should be looking for `Infortis_Ultimo_Helper_Cssgen`), but the admin throws an error looking for another class).

The production setup is **load balanced between two servers** and the code is located on **a shard NFS mount**.  Permissions **are set 755 for directories** and 644 for files, and the **owner is set to the apache user**.  I have confirmed that all the files are present and the module XML file is present as well.

Answer (score 1):

In past,your system had a 3rd party module named `[SomeCompanyName]_Ultimo`.

That module have a helper class `[SomeCompanyName]_Ultimo_Helper_Cssgen`.

That module's class has **been called** using **`Mage::helper('ultimo/cssgen')`**.

May be in your files the code  **`Mage::helper('ultimo/cssgen')`** exists. Due to that reason you **are getting this error**.

Or, may be magento **`compiler is enabled in your system`**. After disabling this module, you did not re-run compiler. You should **re-run compiler if it is enabled.**